# ion-nav-back button not showing up when I move to a component where I'm using ion-nav

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a flow on my ionic app, where I'm starting a subnavigation with the help of `ion-nav`. Now, when I move to this page, I do not see the `ion-back-button` button.

I was want to see / I was expecting that the `ion-back-button` to be present in the header, because this is not a root page (not entered in the stack with `navigateRoot()`, but the `navigateForwards()`) this page is not a root page, its just another page with special thing being that its having ion-nav in it, which I'm using to maintain a subnavigation under it.

So, my question is,why is the ionic treating this page with `ion-nav` differently, than the other pages which are loaded in the stack (Other pages do have `ion-back-button` and is working as expected).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use in your page something like that

```
 <ion-back-button defaultHref="/path" text='Retour'></ion-back-button>
```

[ionicDoc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/nav)

Comment: Actually, I dont want to add this, since this will lead to managing valueHref value based on flow, from where this originated... think of it like something dynamic and not a fixed flow...which means that I can land to this page from different flows.